# Some of material design icons are not defined flutter

Tags: flutter

Hey so I have this problem, I want to use some icons that are listed [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) but in my flutter it says the name isn't defined. I already tried to do flutter clean and the problem still exists (I need to use Icons.password and Icons.person_off). Do you have any idea how to fix it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Go on to the pubspec.yaml file and enable the material dependecies like
**uses-material-design: true** also if you still not found your icon then go to https://fonts.google.com/icons this page and search for your icon and after clicking on your icon it will show you the code for implementing that icon on web, android, flutter and IOS.