# Flutter Material icons: some icons dont exist in the flutter's Icons class

Tags: flutter, material-design, google-material-icons

I realize that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68818470/12555423), but that question does not seem to have any activity so I'm trying to get more attention to this issue.

I am trying to use the `percent` icon from Material icons, although in the fonts.google.com site,it shows flutter implementation (screenshot attached below), when I try to call it from flutter code I get the error `The getter 'percent' isn't defined for the type 'Icons'.` (screenshot attached below).

what is the reason for this, and why is google trying to show some icon is supported for flutter when it clearly is not?

[image: fonts.google.com screenshot that shows that the icon is defined for flutter]

[image: vsc screenshot that shows the error occurring when trying to call the percent icon]

here is my `flutter doctor -v` output:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.1348], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.0 at C:\Users\adnan\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision cf44000065 (23 hours ago), 2021-12-08 14:06:50 -0800
    • Engine revision 40a99c5951
    • Dart version 2.15.0
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\adnan\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jre\bin\java     
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)    
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[!] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to determine bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\adnan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.29.0

[√] VS Code (version 1.61.0-insider)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\adnan\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code Insiders
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • sdk gphone x86 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)            • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.45
    • Edge (web)              • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.43

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: I would use [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html) list. Also make sure in your ```pubsec.yaml``` ```flutter: uses-material-design: true```

Comment: You can use [this lib](https://pub.dev/packages/material_design_icons_flutter) if you want to use the most up-to-date material icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, now with `Flutter 2.10`, they've added some icons.

> [Last but not least, we’ve added 1,028 new Material icons.](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-2-10-5aafb0314b12#:%7E:text=Last%20but%20not%20least%2C%20we%E2%80%99ve%20added%201%2C028%20new%20Material%20icons.)

which kinda answers this question, so the clear answer is whenever we encounter such an issue, we have to just sit and wait for flutter to integrate those icons, or use another Icons package.